# Is it possible to read RIL logs from app continuously?

Tags: android, ril

I want to check for some events that are only reported in RIL logs like when call is active, message is delivered, etc. I know the log statements that are relevant but can't figure out how to continuously access them from RIL logs and use in my app.

Answer (score 0):

For the Log you concerned, they are not reported continuously. If you're interested in call/message event, you should better register broadcast receiver for SMS_DELIVER broadcast, and for call, listen a PhoneStateListener.